# javascript / vscode - how to add/modify default library reference path across run config settings

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

Analogically, I have statements to require packages as given below spread across multi files

```
var program = require('xxx')
var program = require('abc')
var program = require('123')
```

The usual source file folder is in `c:/my_project/resources/libs` where all these folders are kept.

I have another source folder in `c:/a_new_source` where new sources for all the libs are kept.

Is there any preference setting like `default lib ref path` updating which to `c:/a_new_source` would ensure that instead of lifting source libs from `c:/my_project/resources/libs`, the launch config loads the libs from `c:/a_new_source`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be done by adding an environment parameter NODE_PATH containing (delimited by semi colon) all paths to be searched for dependency modules.

```
set NODEPATH=c:/a_new_source;c:/x/;c:/y
```